# variable in php function name

Tags: php, image, variables

I'm wanting to utilise PHP's built-in `imagejpeg` and `imagepng` functions.
I have a variable `$type` which defines the filetype jpeg or png.

I wanted to have one function call.  Something like this:

```
image.$type($image, null, 100);
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [variable variables].(http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should works if you use the full function name in a var

```
$func = "image".$type;
$func($image,null,100);
```

**Careful**: `imagepng` use a quality between 0-9 (not 0 and 100)

for completeness: you should use an approach more solid, using a OOP method with [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).
However I don't know your situation and your code. So it's just a note.